# Two WordPress Containers on Kitematic

Tags: wordpress, docker

I've setup Kitematic for Windows 10. I have a sql db (Percona) and two WordPress containers, one for plugin dev and one for theme dev.

I setup the plugin container first, then installed a second container for the theme dev. Now, whenever I start up the wp/theme (installed second) container my browser redirects to the ip/port of the wp container i configured first.

I'm new to kitematic/docker...so is this an error? Should I be exposing the port for the second container by setting an environmental variable for the second container?

Comment: if both containers are dependent on each other you need to link those containers and you have to expose required PORTS also.

Comment: They are not dependent on each other. I do not use them at the same time but independently of each other.